# how to append <div> dynamically to created <div>using server side logic not by using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery

I know by using jQuery logic we can append n numbers of `<div>'s` dynamically to already created `<div>` but my question is, Can we write server side logic to create a dynamic `<div>'s` when the page is loaded (same like jQuery logic).

This is jQuery logic

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var i=0,length=2;

     for(i; i<=length;i++)
 {
  $('#footer-div').append($('<div class="dynamic"><h3 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Dynamic div creating</h3></div>')); 
 }

)};
```

Please suggest me is it possible to create dynamic `<div>'s` by using server side logic using asp.net c#?

If it is possible then what is the main difference between jQuery logic and server side logic?

And which is the best approach to achieve this ?

Please suggest me with example code.

Thanks

Comment: You can use server-side to generate HTML - as a string.  You can't use server-side to manipulate the DOM - the elements within the browser.  So you make an ajax call to the server, it returns some HTML and you use javascript (with or without jquery) to add that HTML into the DOM - this is the process to add "dynamic divs" to the page.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for your comment and  I understand and as per your comment please clarify  this point also then I understand very clearly that is,  `We can't handle any kind of dynamic logic of HTML tags creation from server side and if we want like that we must use Ajax call[WebMethod] right ? ` please clarify this point.

Comment: You can apply any logic at server side just make sure your whole HTML is stored in string properly.

Comment: Server can't change DOM.